# highchart dual x axis with different datetime interval

Tags: highcharts

I want to compare two interval of a data series (eg. this year and last year), so I need dual x axis, and two series.

```
    xAxises: [
           {
                min: Date.parse('2014-01-01 00:00'),
                max: Date.parse('2014-12-31 23:59'),
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%Y.%m.%d.',
                    minute: '%H:%M',
                }
            },
                            {
                min: Date.parse('2015-01-10 00:00'),
                max: Date.parse('2015-12-31 23:59'),
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%Y.%m.%d.',
                    minute: '%H:%M',
                },               
            }
   ]
```

I see the series, I can zoom in, but zoom out and reset zoom not working by the second series/x axis. How can I plot this two series using Highchart?

Thanks!

(A demo is here: https://jsfiddle.net/e1o3jov3/)

Comment: Please recreate your exampel as live demo. (In the Highcahrts should be xAxis not xAxises)

Comment: Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e1o3jov3/

Comment: You can catch [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) event and then call setExtrmes on second axis. https://jsfiddle.net/hpLyzogf/

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thank you!